# implement/invoke Excel Solver from java

Tags: java, solver

I have an application in Java/JSF, I need to do some optimization calculations, like Excel Solver Add-in does, one option is certainly to write my own solver implementation, but I'm kind of short of time, so I'm looking into libraries that already exist that can help me with this.

Can you recommend any libraries?

**EDITED**

I don't have the algorithm yet, but I know that I will have to do similar actions like in Excel Solver - defining parameters, the goal and restrictions and calculation the MAX/MIN revenue

Comment: Elaborate on what you need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a complete solution, but this may get you on the right track (what you are looking for is a non-linear parametric optimizer/solver):

http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/html/index.html

I did some Googling, and I was surprised that I wasn't able to find something right away...

Here is info about Excel's specific algorithm:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/82890  (again, not a solution, but certainly interesting information for anyone who does this sort of thing).

And here's the company that actually wrote the Excel solver:  http://www.solver.com/sdkplatform2.htm
Not sure what your budget is, but if time is of the essence, it may make sense to license it (not sure if they have a Java version of their sdk or not).

And a related question at SO:  [Solving nonlinear equations numerically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540414/solving-nonlinear-equations-numerically)